# How to read array of structs from another contract in solidity (UniswapV3 TickLens.sol)

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity, smartcontracts

How do I read the data of `contractA` in `contractB`, if the data I want to read is an array of structs?

I want to get the data from in `ContractA`:

```
    function getPopulatedTicksInWord(address pool, int16 tickBitmapIndex)
        public
        view
        override
        returns (PopulatedTick[] memory populatedTicks)
```

link to the contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xbfd8137f7d1516D3ea5cA83523914859ec47F573#code
(it is the only function in TickLens.sol)

I tried the following in ContractB, which shall call getPopulatedTicksInWord of ContractA and then return the struct array further in my code:

```
contract Lib_UniswapV3
{
    ...
    struct PopulatedTick {
        int24 tick;
        int128 liquidityNet;
        uint128 liquidityGross;        
    }
}

abstract contract UniswapV3TickLens is Lib_UniswapV3
{
    function getPopulatedTicksInWord(address poolAddress, int16 tickBitmapIndex) external virtual returns (PopulatedTick[] memory);
}

contract ContractB is
    Lib_UniswapV3   
{

    function getExchangePriceInputData(
        address poolAddress
        )         
        public  
        returns (PriceInputData[] memory priceInputData)
        {   
            ...
            PopulatedTick[] memory ticks;
            (ticks) = UniswapV3TickLens(0xbfd8137f7d1516D3ea5cA83523914859ec47F573).getPopulatedTicksInWord(address(0x8ad599c3A0ff1De082011EFDDc58f1908eb6e6D8), int16(12));        
            ...

        }
}
```

For now, I just hardcoded the input data. If you perform that call (on etherscan) you will receive that struct array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by

- you want to implement the function getPopulatedTicksInWord of ContractA into your contractB, instead of just calling it from ContractB.
- mark it as internal
- dont test with input params that create a lot of calls, if using hardhat. it somehow can not deal with too many requests.